# Magento 2 - Get Request Params / Api Request Params From Plugin

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, plugin

I am trying to access request parameters made to the api url which I am setting a response for via a plugin.

The call is to: **rest/default/V1/guest-carts/a9e6330920e85d09a123a396f77a9275/shipping-information**

Here is the code that I am currently using, however it provides an empty array.

```
namespace Vendor\Onepage\Plugin;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

protected $_request;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
)
{
    var_dump($this->_request->getParams());
    die('testing');
}

}
```

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you are using wrong class in your `construct` for `$request`. Change your `construct` to following and it should work:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

After that you can get REST request's parameters in following way:

```
var_dump($this->_request->getParams());
```

Do clear necessary caches after the above change.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the line

```
var_dump($this->_request->getParams());
```

to

```
var_dump($subject->_request->getParams());
```